# How to exclude certain files while using GetFiles()

Tags: c#, linq, getfiles

I have a Folder containing 2 subfolders each containing around 1000 files. The files look like this:

> 38485303_SARA_N211_T.ygx
>     38485303_SARA_N211_B.ygx
>     38208001_ULTI_CARTRI.ygx

I want 3 separate arrays - 2 of which I already have.

```
 Array 1 = all files ending with "_T."
 Array 2 = all files ending with "_B."
 Array 3 = all files that dont end with _T or _B
```

This is what I have for array 1 and 2.

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*_T.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*_B.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And this is what I've tried to form array 3 without any success:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, ".ygx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(file => !file.EndsWith("_T.ygx") || !file.EndsWith("_B.ygx")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Simply get all the files. based on the extention and then either filter them with LinQ or enumerate them and act acording to how they are named

Comment: This is a common mistake. You say "must be different from X or different from Y", every filename will be different from at least one of those. Think about "where X is different from 10 or x is different from 15". 2 will be different from both, 10 will be different from 15 and 15 will be different from 10. Usually the correct approach is to use AND, not OR.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen thanks this explanation together with the example of Kay Nelson helped me! Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could work.

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, ".ygx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(file => !file.EndsWith("_T.ygx") && !file.EndsWith("_B.ygx")).ToArray();
```

Now you ensure that files that dont end with `_T.ygx AND ALSO _B.ygx`

Answer (score 1):

Simply get all the files. based on the extention and then either filter them with LinQ or enumerate them and act according to how they are named.

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.ygx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var arraySuffixT = allFiles.Where( f=> f.EndsWith("_T.ygx")).ToArray();
var arraySuffixB = allFiles.Where( f=> f.EndsWith("_B.ygx")).ToArray();
var arrayNoSuffix = allFiles.Where(f=> !f.EndsWith("_T.ygx") && !f.EndsWith("_B.ygx")).ToArray();
```

If you only want to enumerate all the files once:

```
var listSuffixT = new List<string>();
var listSuffixB = new List<string>();
var listNoSuffix = new List<string>();

foreach(var file in allFiles){
    if(f.EndsWith("_T.ygx")){
        listSuffixT.Add(file);
    }
    else if(f.EndsWith("_B.ygx")){
        listSuffixB.Add(file);
    }
    else{
        listNoSuffix.Add(file);
    }

}
```

But perhaps you don't need to materialize the 3 collection and can dispatch to the right process